# What is the best way to have synchronized a collection of objects between various threads in .Net?

Tags: multithreading

What is the best way to have synchronized a collection of objects between various threads in .Net?

I need to have a List or Dictionary accessed from different threads in a thread safe mode. With Adds, Removes, Foreachs, etc.

Comment: You may want to be more clear about what you're trying to do here.  The responses already about a queue or a hashtable may be appropriate or not to your problem -- with what you've said, it's hard to tell.  A rough description of the problem may get you more appropriate answers.

Comment: Agreed.  One factor is whether you need the collection to be strongly-typed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a lock-free queue:

http://www.boyet.com/Articles/LockfreeQueue.html

Or handle the synchronization yourself using locks:

http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.html#_Locking

Answer (score 1):

Basically it depends on the pattern you need to use.
If you have several threads writing and reading the same place you can use the same data structure that you would have used with a single thread (hastable, array, etc.) with a lock/monitor or a ReaderWriterLock to prevent race conditions.
In case you need to pass data between threads you'll need some kind of queue (synced or lockfree) that thread(s) of group A would insert to and thread(s) of group B would deque from. You might want to use WaitEvent (AutoReset or Manual) so that you won't loose CPU when the queue is empty. 
It really depends on what kind of workflow you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Hashtable.Synchronized method returns a synchronized (thread safe) wrapper for the Hashtable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.synchronized(VS.80).aspx

This also exists for other collections.

Answer (score 0):

A number of the collection classes in .Net have built in support for synchronizing and making access from multiple threads safe.  For example (in C++/CLR):

```
    Collections::Queue ^unsafe_queue = gcnew Collections::Queue();
    Collections::Queue ^safe_queue = Collections::Queue::Synchronized(unsafe_queue);
```

You can throw away the reference to unsafe_queue, and keep the reference to safe_queue.  It can be shared between threads, and you're guaranteed thread safe access.  Other collection classes, like ArrayList and Hashtable, also support this, in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing specifics, I'd lean towards delegates and events to notify of changes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17sde2xt(VS.71).aspx

And implementing the Observer or Publish Subscribe pattern

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978603.aspx